# What happens if a Dropbox folder is encrypted by WannaCrypt / WannaCry?

Tags: ransomware, cloud-storage, wannacry, dropbox

Does one's Dropbox "data in the cloud" also get encrypted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your local files get encrypted and synced they will also be encrypted in your online folders. Luckily Dropbox supports file versioning (https://www.dropbox.com/help/security/recover-older-versions) so if you happened to have your files in Dropbox get encrypted you can restore them easily.